# Unable to create new react app with npx create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I am trying to create new react app with `npx create-react-app [name]` command. But I get following error:

> error Couldn't find package "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types@7.9.0" required by "babel-preset-react-app@^9.1.2" on the "npm" registry.

Each time it is saying some **package could not be found** on npm registry (not only @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types@7.9.0 this package).

I have also updated my `npm` and `npx`, but no success.

Answer (score 2):

You can try deleting the `.npmrc` file located in `Users/you/.npmrc` and run the command again, seems there is a bug with npm and this is a workaround